# SQL Server 2008 R2 update from stored procedure reflects delay

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a very strange issue going in my SQL Server 2008 R2 and the stored procedures we have written.

We have written a stored procedure for our inventory management system and there are place where we do update and the parameters to stored procedure are sent via our C# windows app.

Everything works fine but the strange thing is that when the update happens (consider there are quite a few rows that gets updated at a given point of time) as we construct and pass list of IDs that needs to be updated.

The update doesn't reflect immediately but rather takes a few hours [in my research it has taken around 10+ hours & sometimes almost an entire day].

Any guess what could be the issue?

Comment: Does it take 10 hours for SP to run or SP finishes fast and updated values don't appear right away? Also  what happens if you run SP directly in SSMS?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code of the SP?  Are you using Transactions?  Perhaps you are beginning a transaction and you don't see the updates until after a commit?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter the SP runs and finishes quickly, its just the updated result that is taking time to reflect in the Windows app or sometime even SSMS aswell.

Comment: @user2480596 - SP transaction BEGIN/COMMIT works fine and the commit happens accordingly, because after the taken time, the data is updated correctly. Pulling out sample code is very difficult at this moment.

Comment: Any scheduled jobs that only process updates every few hours? Any strange triggers?

Comment: I would look at triggers that are doing a lot of work, and perhaps they are firing recursively or the nesting level is too deep.

Comment: Are you caching any data?  If so, perhaps the cache needs to be reset/cleared after updates happen.

Comment: @HABO we have couple of triggers but that is not active during transactions and is not connected to the transaction tables. But "job schedule" does ring bell. I need to check with the DB admin at my clients place and then see. Also, is there any suggestion to speed up the "schedule jobs"> [Update] Job schedule is for taking DB backup on a daily basis.

Comment: @db_brad there is no caching of any data, no views or no background calculations that runs.